# Top and bottom panels disappeared in Ubuntu 10.10 (Gnome)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-panel

For some reason my top and bottom panels have disappeared. I can't right-click and add a new panel either. I tried executing gnome-panel from the terminal, rebooting, but no luck. Any idea how to recover these panels?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that uninstalling Evolution also removed gnome-panel (?!?). I rebooted in recovery mode, then dropped into a netroot shell (terminal with net access) and installed gnome-panel via apt and the panels returned on the next normal boot.

Comment: 'Twas odd that when I attempted to execute gnome-panel earlier, it didn't tell me that it wasn't installed. But whatever.

Comment: You should open a bug report at your distribution (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.) bug tracking system. It's obviously a small problem that needs to be fixed :-)

Comment: Woot? Last time when I tried to remove evolution Ubuntu told me that I would have to remove gnome-desktop as well. Didn't that happen to you?